# upgrade symfony3.4 with bundles extension to symfony4 flex

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, upgrade, symfony4

I have a project in symfony 3.4 then I tried to upgrade to symfony 4 /flex.
the problem is in my code there a 3 bundles TBAdminBundle, TBPlatformBundle and TBSecurityBundle.

Also for each bundle there Extension class exemple.

```
    class TBPlatformExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new PlatformConfiguration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    if (!in_array(strtolower($config['db_driver']), array('custom', 'mongodb', 'orm'))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid db driver "%s".', $config['db_driver']));
    }

    if ('custom' !== $config['db_driver']) {
        $loader->load(sprintf('%s.yml', $config['db_driver']));
        $def = new Definition('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager', array('%tb_notification.model_manager_name%'));
        $def->setPublic(false);

        if (method_exists($def, 'setFactory')) {
            $def->setFactory(array(new Reference('doctrine'), 'getManager'));
        } else {
            // To be removed when dependency on Symfony DependencyInjection is bumped to 2.6
            $def->setFactoryService('doctrine');
            $def->setFactoryMethod('getManager');
        }

        $container->setDefinition('tb_notification.entity_manager', $def);
    }

    foreach (array('form', 'command', 'events') as $basename) {
        $loader->load(sprintf('%s.yml', $basename));
    }

    $container->setParameter('tb_notification.model_manager_name', $config['model_manager_name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_notification.form.notification.type', $config['form']['notification']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_notification.form.notification.name', $config['form']['notification']['name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_trip.form.trip.type', $config['form']['trip']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_trip.form.trip.name', $config['form']['trip']['name']);

    $container->setParameter(
        'tb_notification.form.delete_notification.type',
        $config['form']['delete_notification']['type']
    );
    $container->setParameter(
        'tb_notification.form.delete_notification.name',
        $config['form']['delete_notification']['name']
    );

    $container->setParameter('tb_trip.form.trip.update_trip.type', $config['form']['update_trip']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_trip.form.trip.update_trip.name', $config['form']['update_trip']['name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_action.form.action.type', $config['form']['action']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_action.form.action.name', $config['form']['action']['name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_place.form.place.type', $config['form']['place']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_place.form.place.name', $config['form']['place']['name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_action_privacy.form.action.type', $config['form']['privacy']['type']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_action_privacy.form.action.name', $config['form']['privacy']['name']);

    $container->setParameter('tb_notification.model.notification.class', $config['class']['model']['notification']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_trip.model.trip.class', $config['class']['model']['trip']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_like.model.like.class', $config['class']['model']['like']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_helpful.model.helpful.class', $config['class']['model']['helpful']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_action.model.action.class', $config['class']['model']['action']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_budget.model.class', $config['class']['model']['budget']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_action.model.action_privacy_policy.class', $config['class']['model']['privacy']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_rating.model.rating.class', $config['class']['model']['vote']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_place.model.place.class', $config['class']['model']['place']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_destination.model.destination.class', $config['class']['model']['destination']);

    // parameters for hydrating object with doctrine
    $container->setParameter('tb_action.hydrate.action', $config['hydrate']['action']);
    $container->setParameter('tb_google.key', $config['google']['key']);
    $container->setParameter('compare_text.default_percent', $config['compare']['text']);

    $container->setAlias('tb_trip.manager.trip', $config['service']['manager']['trip']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_like.manager.post', $config['service']['manager']['like']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_helpful.manager.post', $config['service']['manager']['helpful']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_budget_manager', $config['service']['manager']['budget']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_place_manager', $config['service']['manager']['place']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_destination_manager', $config['service']['manager']['destination']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_compare_string', 'similar_text.manager');
    $container->setAlias('foursquare.manager', 'foursquare.manager.default');
    $container->setAlias('tb_action.form_factory', $config['service']['form_factory']['action']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_place.form_factory', $config['service']['form_factory']['place']);
    $container->setAlias('tb_action_privacy.form_factory', $config['service']['form_factory']['privacy']);
    $container->setAlias(
        'tb_notification.form_factory.notification',
        $config['service']['form_factory']['notification']
    );
    $container->setAlias('tb_trip.form_factory', $config['service']['form_factory']['trip']);
    $container->setAlias(
        'tb_notification.form_factory.notification_delete',
        $config['service']['form_factory']['delete_notification']
    );


    $container->setAlias('tb_action.customer_repository', 'tb_action.customer_repository_default');
    $container->setAlias('tb_notification.customer_repository', 'tb_notification.customer_repository_default');
    $container->setAlias('tb_trip.customer_repository', 'tb_trip.customer_repository_default');
}
```

}

According to documentation

"In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and bundles should only be used to share code and features between multiple applications."

I know this it's no more possible with symfony4/flex
How can I rewrite this to match with flex configuration?

thanks

Comment: You can still use bundles in S4 especially if they need extensions and what not.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to migrate progressively your bundles.

### 1. Put the bundle in the src of your SF4 application like this :

```
src/ 
   Bundle/ 
       TBAdminBundle 
       TBPlatformBundle 
       TBSecurityBundle 
   Command    
   Controller     
   Entity
    ...
```

### 2. Use Composer PSR-4 to autoload them (composer.json)

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "src/",
        "TBAdminBundle\\" : "src/Bundle/TBAdminBundle/",
        "TBPlatformBundle\\" : "src/Bundle/TBPlatformBundle/",
        "TBSecurityBundle\\" : "src/Bundle/TBSecurityBundle/",
        ...
```

### 3. Exclude them from App Services autoload (config/services.yaml)

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    # you can exclude directories or files
    # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Repository,Bundle}'
```

### 4. Validate the new installation/configuration

Although SF4 is bundle less for core App application, it supports bundle ... Just check that you resolve all deprecated functions from those bundles

### 5. Start progressive migration of your bundles code:

As Hint :

- Rework your config/parameters to use ENV, and services.yaml parameters 
  So you can transfer most config variables/parameters to the App level and easily share them ...
- All your services definitions can be moved from Extention classes into services.yaml for simplicity and easy maintenance.
- You will degrease bundles code as time go and you gain experience with the new SF4 services usability and orientations.

Answer (score 0):

That note tells you that it is no longer a recommendation but it doesn't mean that you should refactor your code completely. If you already have your code packed as bundles you should only remove deprecated code. In general it is a good idea to pack your code in bundles only if it is reusable across projects.

Comment: I know that we can use bundles with SF4 but when we use flex we must reorganize the code under src/* so that there no more TBAdminBundle/, TBPlatformBundle and TBSecurityBundle under src/ .

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#upgrade-to-flex
Following theses steps I have to move php classes into src/ except bundle specific files (like AppBundle.php and DependencyInjection/).
the problem is the code above is under DependencyInjection/ then I don't want to remove it